# Meteor Android Setup

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

I am trying to get the android platform working in my newly created Meteor application. I have followed this guide from start to finish. However, instead of being successful, I am left with this error message

```
android: added platform

Your system does not yet seem to fulfill all requirements to build apps for Android.

Please follow the installation instructions in the mobile guide:
http://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#installing-prerequisites

Status of the individual requirements:
SUCCESS Java JDK
SUCCESS Android SDK
✗ Android target: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set
the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
✗ Gradle: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.
Looked here: C:\Users\Keevan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\templates\gradle\wrapper
```

Any help is greatly appreciated as I am at a loss as to what to do next!

Comment: Follow the link it gives

Comment: I go into tools/ and the folder templates does not exist!

Comment: Right... `Android SDK not found`. That's the folder it looked at, but it cannot find anything

Comment: You need to set environement variables first. 

Declare Environment variable

    export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/Library/Android/sdk"
    export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
(path for you might vary depending where you installed Android)